# how to make a mutex lock among programs, liike mutex lock among processes

Tags: linux, multiprocessing, mutex

in a remote host, I want to run 3 programs A , B and C
but I want them to run at different time
so if A is running, B and C can't run

my idea is to create a mutex lock among these programs
like mutex lock between processes

initial idea is to create a mutex stuff
e,g, when A is running, it lock the stuff
so B and C can't access or write on the stuff
then B and C knows there is a program is running, and they wait until the stuff is unblocked

the stuff could be a file or something

can anyone give some ideas?
I hope I can operate with shell scripts, like

```
 if file is unlocked; then
 lock file
./programA
 unlock file
 fi
```

thanks

Comment: `boost::interprocess` has mutexes that can be placed in shared memory and accessed by multiple processes.

Comment: it is mutex between processes in the same source codes, what I want are mutex stuff among independent programs

Comment: Which programming language? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea of using a lock file is actually a fairly common idiom. It's usually used to make sure that no more than one copy of a program is running at one time. Conventionally the file is named something like `~/.foo_lock` or `~/foo/.lock` where `foo` identifies the program.

I don't remember the details of how this is generally implemented, but try `man flock` for a starting point. I can't recall off the top of my head the name of an open source program that does this. I think however, that `gnucash` would be such a program, along with numerous mail clients.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a standard pthread mutex but you will need to explicitely initialize its attributes to "process-shared" with the [pthread_mutexattr_setpshared()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_mutexattr_setpshared.html) function. Then you can pass the mutex to other processes within a shared memory.

Comment: it is mutex between processes, what I want are mutex stuff among independent programs

Comment: Independent programs are different processes. The solution is to store the mutex in a shared memory object (shared by all programs) but it needs to be initialised as process-shared.

Comment: it seems very complex, is there a simpler way, like create a mutex-style file, which can be operated using shell scripts?

Comment: There are many ways to solve this sort of problem, please complete your question. Maybe lockfile will be more appropriate if it's for scripts? http://linux.die.net/man/1/lockfile

Comment: is there anything that is not clear ? thanks